# bot framework embedded chat 403 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, botframework

I am using the embedded chat control to hook up to my Microsoft Bot Framework bot and I keep getting these errors:

(I'm using Node.js on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. None of these errors happen when I run the code locally)

jquery.min.js:11 POST https://webchat.botframework.com/api/conversations/null/messages 403 (Forbidden)

The bot doesn't respond and a few minutes later it shows this:

jquery.min.js:11 GET https://webchat.botframework.com/api/conversations/Bv3bkhOgxas/messages?watermark=131101401454109138 403 (Forbidden)

which is sometimes accompanied by a 500 (Internal Server Error)

I assume the null in the first message is a clue. Does anyone know what is going on or how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you are doing w/o additional detail.  But it's likely your header either doesn't contain an auth token or the incorrect one.